# Localization Resources .NET - how to keep them synchronized?

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, resources, localization

When we follow localization guidelines we endup with at least a couple of resource files.

`Resource.resx` and `Resource.CI.resx` which is a specific `CultureInfo` resource.
Lets say we add a hundred string pairs in `Resource.resx` and want to translate those keys in another resource. we can copy paste them right now and translate them and it might work the first time.

However after we translate strings it becomes hard to keep files synchronized - it reorders strings automatically and I currently don't understand what is the supposed way to make sure each string is localized.

Since resource strings are supposed to be kind of linked with each other and with extra job that is done to make sure satellite assemblies are built correctly I was hoping theres a function like 'make sure each resource string is present in localized resource file' but I am afraid that one is missing..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[RESX Synchroniser](https://web.archive.org/web/20130817214843/http://www.screwturn.eu/ResxSync.ashx) might do you what you are looking for

> When you edit the .NET Resource files
>   in Visual Studio, either manually and
>   using the "Generate Local Resources"
>   command, the IDE updates only the
>   culture-invariant resources: if you
>   have a resource file called
>   Messages.aspx, the files in other
>   languages, say Messages.it-IT.resx,
>   are not updated, and you have to do
>   that manually. RESX Synchronizer will
>   help you keep the resource files
>   synchronized, adding the new keys to
>   the localized files, and removing the
>   deleted ones. Comments are preserved
>   during the process.

Comment: looks promising! at least description. However its been for unsupported like three years - do you think we can rely on it?

Comment: I dont know for sure but I dont think much has changed in how vs deals with resx in a while so why not

Comment: You can still find it on [http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15697/RESX-Synchronizer](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15697/RESX-Synchronizer)

Answer (score 4):

I just found http://zetaresourceeditor.codeplex.com/ as well seems like a similar idea to the others

Comment: I will go with this one... not an automated thing but can do the trick. And it is free.

Answer (score 3):

may be `UnitTest` can help you? you know, which text each control should have, once you create them, after just add new strings to list and compare the values. after once hard working you can test your localization works right.

Comment: This solution sounds like a lot of duplicated code to me. Can't say that unittesting resource files sounds like a good plan to me.

Comment: Lets wait for a best solution!

Comment: imho, the localization provided by .net out of the box is not that great. If localization is going to be important, I'd advice searching for alternatives...

Comment: I guess your right. However application is fairly easy atm and out of the box localization can do the job currently I believe.

Answer (score 3):

a little old this discussion, but still interesting. have a look at [ResXManager](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/3b64e04c-e8de-4b97-8358-06c73a97cc68)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you create culture specific resource files programmatically using the Resx file for that Winform.
You can create a small app which you could run time to time.

Create  XML kind of file for each culture like fr.XML, fill that with the Union of all the strings in your project.And provide the translations there itself like, for example that file in french might look like the following..

```
< wordTranslation>
< Word>Hello< /Word>
< Translation>Bonjour< /Translation>
< /wordTranslation>
```

Create a hashtable or some data structure which would best act as dictionary for each culture, fill it with data from the culture specific XMl files like frDictionary.

For Each Resx file in your project for example wind1.resx , create a culture specific file like wind1.fr.resx.
Read words from wind1.resx, find the translation of the word from the frDictionayry.
Write it to wind1.fr.resx.

You can keep updating your translations in the XML file.
So its a one time effort.
This way you can keep it synchornised and easily maintainable.

Answer (score 1):

I know this has already been given traditional answers, but I would also like to put forward something completely original we tried (and succeeded) doing ourselves for more efficient localisation of Silverlight:

[Localisation of Silverlight projects after completion](http://blog.hitechmagic.com/?cat=23)

(*Resx is so "last century"*)

Answer (score 0):

You mean synchronize translations between those files? Use http://www.getlocalization.com and upload both as master files, when they are translated the translations are populated to all your files.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try [Amanuens](http://amanuens.com). It's developed by the same author of RESX Synchronizer and besides help keeping resource files synchronized (even automatically into your repository if you set it), can be used to give your translators access to strings to be translated in a very powerful and easy to use web editor.

Answer (score 0):

In 2023, the best option is to use a Visual Studio Extension: [ResXManager](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TomEnglert.ResXManager). It allows you to view strings and all translations in a single view.